# Concatenate multiple lists of lists in python

Tags: python, python-itertools

I have a list of multiple list-of-lists in python:

```
a = [[[0,1,2], [10,11,12]],
     [[3,4,5], [13,14,15]]]
```

And I would like to merge all the first lists together, the second lists together, and so forth:

```
final = [[0,1,2,3,4,5],
         [10,11,12,13,14,15]]
```

The furthest I've got is to try to unzip the outer lists:

```
zip(*a) = [([0,1,2], [3,4,5]), 
           ([10,11,12], [13,14,15])]
```

I suppose one could loop through these and then chain each together, but that seems wasteful. What's a pythonic way to fix this?

**NOTE**: 
There might be more than two sublists in each "row".

Answer (score 3, accepted):

A combination of [`zip()`](https://docs.python.org/3/library/functions.html#zip) and [`itertools.chain()`](https://docs.python.org/3/library/itertools.html#itertools.chain) would do it:

```
In [1]: from itertools import chain

In [2]: [list(chain(*lists)) for lists in zip(*a)]
Out[2]: [[0, 1, 2, 3, 4, 5], [10, 11, 12, 13, 14, 15]]
```

Answer (score 1):

The `reduce` function is the perfect fit for this kind of problems:

```
[reduce((lambda x,y: x[i]+y[i]), a) for i,_ in enumerate(a)]
```

Result:

```
[[0, 1, 2, 3, 4, 5], [10, 11, 12, 13, 14, 15]]
```

This code reads: For each index `i`, collect all the `i`th items of the elements of `a` together.